# MS project : how to check in VBA if a column is visible in tasks view?

Tags: vba, ms-project

I wrote a VBA macro in MSP to insert a column (TaskColumn Flag20) to display specific indicator. It works well except that it creates the column each time I open the project file. Hence I am looking for a way to check if the column exists and is visible when opening file. I couldn't find any information on such possibility.

Many thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to get all of the visible columns programmatically

```
'The function returns all of the visible column names as a delimiter separated string.
'   Call with a string as the first parameter to represent a custom delimiter, or leave
'   blank to use the default of a comma ,
Function GetColumns(Optional customDelimeter As String) As String
    If customDelimeter = "" Then customDelimeter = ","  'handle custom delimeter

    Dim viewableColumns As String 'create return value

    SelectRow Row:=1, RowRelative:=False 'select the 1st row then parse all columns composing that row
    For Each lngFieldID In MSProject.ActiveSelection.FieldIDList
        Dim columnName As String
        If lngFieldID > 0 Then

            'convert the column ID to a string of the field name, either custom or built-in
            columnName = Trim((CustomFieldGetName(lngFieldID)))
            If Len(columnName) = 0 Then
              columnName = Trim(FieldConstantToFieldName(lngFieldID)) ' use the built-in field name
            End If

            'append return value
            viewableColumns = viewableColumns & customDelimeter & columnName
        End If
    Next

    'get rid of the first delimeter
    If Len(viewableColumns) > 0 Then
        viewableColumns = Right(viewableColumns, Len(viewableColumns) - 1)
    End If

    GetColumns = viewableColumns

End Function
```

Comment: Oh very nice! I didn't thought the FieldConstantToFieldName could help me there. I will have a look. Many thanks Jerred!

Answer (score 1):

A better idea might be to create/edit a specific view with a custom table that includes the columns you want. Then you don't have to check anything, just choose that view and it will always give you what you want.

If you want to automate showing the view then write a macro that uses the [Application.ViewApplyEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Project-VBA/articles/application-viewapplyex-method-project) method.

Answer (score 1):

Final working code.

```vb
Public Sub CheckFlag20Column()
    SelectRow Row:=1, RowRelative:=False 'select the 1st row then parse all columns composing that row
    For Each lngFieldID In MSProject.ActiveSelection.FieldIDList
        Dim columnName As String
        If lngFieldID > 0 Then
            columnName = Trim(FieldConstantToFieldName(lngFieldID)) ' use the built-in field name
            If columnName = "Flag20" Then
                SelectTaskColumn Column:="Flag20"
                ColumnDelete
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the interest is in testing a single column, try this.
Works for either its constant name or the user assigned custom name.

```vb
    Public Function IsColumnVisible(Name As String)
        IsColumnVisible = False
        On Error GoTo LeaveIsColumnVisible
        SelectTaskColumn Column:=Name ' Will error out if the column is hidden
        IsColumnVisible = True
    LeaveIsColumnVisible:
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution does not need to select a row. It can be used for tables that are not visible.

```
Function GetColumns() As Variant
Dim myTable As Table
Dim myColumn As TableField
Dim arColumn() As String
Dim i As Integer

Set myTable = activeProject.TaskTables(activeProject.CurrentTable)
ReDim arColumn(myTable.TableFields.Count - 1)

i = 0
For Each myColumn In myTable.TableFields
    If myColumn .Width > 0 Then
        arColumn(i) = FieldConstantToFieldName(myColumn.Field)
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next myColumn

GetColumns = arColumn 
End Function
```